# Amazon s3 - Downloads show as corrupt for some users but not for others

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, corruption

I'm having a strange problem where some users (all using Mac) are reporting that files downloaded from our S3 storage are corrupt (even after re-downloads). I have tried downloading the files myself on both Windows, Ubuntu and OSX and they all work for me, but I am not sure I have used the exact same browser/OS combo as they have.

Are there some headers needed for file downloads that are required for some browsers/OS combination in order for the file to be ok? Or is there something else that I should look up?

I kind of assume that any http-headers are moot once the file has been downloaded to the drive and you try to open it from there, but I am trying to figure out if there is anything I can do on the server end or if the problem lies with the users computers.

Not quite sure if this is a StackOverflow question, perhaps it is better at Server Fault or Super User? Never really use those sites so I am not sure.

Comment: Just a pure file download ? no extra server-side code to retrieve the download file ?

Comment: It's a CORS request, so we generate a token that tells S3 to allow the download but we don't touch the file itself. That goes directly from Amazon to the user.

Comment: You can debug by tracing the server response in the machine that corrupts the download using browser's developer console

Comment: What kind of files?  Are you setting the `Content-type` header correctly on the S3 objects?  It "shouldn't" matter once the file is downloaded but given the Mac's propensity to try to think for the user, it might.  I've seen problems on Macs where users could not open downloaded XLSX files where the mime type was misconfigured on the web server.

Comment: I think the Content-type might be wrong (I think they are defaulted in some cases) so if Mac messes with the files based on the Content-type then that might be it. I'll try changing the content-type of one of the affected files and see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Also check `Content-Encoding` and if you use gzip/deflate make sure the actual content on S3 is stored in that format.